# Legal to publish books based on SE questions & answers?

Tags: discussion, legal

One of my SE comrades stumbled across a book on Amazon which seems to basically be a direct ripoff of questions & answers posted to Stack Exchange. Upon further investigation, it appears that the "author" is actually trying to make a career out of this...

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&text=George+A+Duckett&search-alias=books&field-author=George+A+Duckett&sort=relevancerank

Seems pretty shady to me, so I was wondering: **is this even legal?**

---

I've seen a [related thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/royalties-from-a-stack-overflow-sourced-book), but I don't believe this is a dupe. That thread is asking about *royalties* for using *specific* questions/answers, whereas this guy on Amazon seems to be wholesale copying entire branches of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Good find, thanks @animuson! I searched Meta, but that question didn't turn up. (I guess because I searched the word "book" instead of "ebook".)